# What does the word "round" mean in football (soccer) term?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "round" mean in football (soccer) context?

HUGE CHANCE! Magennis feeds KLP through. He **rounds** the goalkeeper but the angle is narrow for the winger as he flashes his effort across the face of goal. Unlucky!

Comment: Was there video accompanying this commentary? What action appeared on the screen as this was said? Can you relate that to a possible meaning of *round*?

Comment: Have you looked up *round* in a dictionary?  You should do basic research before asking a question here.

Comment: to round here means to go around and it will not be in the dictionary here in a way that will help you. So, he gets on the other side of the goalie but cannot make the goal anyway. Please bear in mind that neither this question nor your previous question are really "about" football. These things exist in the language anyway.

Comment: This is in the dictionary with the appropriate meaning, although *round* has so many meanings it may be hard to find.  In the sentence "He rounds the goalkeeper", *round* is clearly a transitive verb, and [in Merriam-Webster, the second definition of *round* as a transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round) is "GO AROUND".

Comment: You're more likely to see this (verb) use of ***round*** in contexts like ***He rounded the corner*** (he went/came round the corner), rather than *rounding **the goalie*** (or some other obstruction in one's intended path).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe this could either be made an answer or the question closed for not looking in the dictionary first, if that's a reason to close?

Comment: @A.B.: You've recently posted several comments suggesting that some of ***my*** comments should be formally posted as "Answers". But I don't understand why you're singling ***me*** out for this particular treatment. At least ***two*** preceding comments have actually given far more extensive definitions (one even has a link the the relevant dictionary source). What makes you think that my "peripheral" comment about a very subtle "usage preference" should be made into an answer, whereas you don't seem to think that about the far more informative contributions from Lambie and stangdon here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can only ping one person in a comment and I had a vague idea it would be considered spammy to post three comments - simple as that.  If you think it *would* have been all right to post separate pings to everybody, I will in future.  I did think yours was the clearer explanation, but I was tired at the time and still am, so if you disagree that may account for it.  As for why I've been sending you a lot of them, you've posted a lot of comments-as-answers that I thought were good, simple as that!  I have been pinging some other people too, it's not just you.

Comment: If I'm spamming too much, let me know.  I'm often not sure what's considered OK, even after reading what rules I can find, so I just try things and see if they're OK.

Comment: @A.B.: I'm certainly not accusing you of spamming! I'm quite satisfied with your response here, if you will be satisfied to accept that I won't always (even, *often*) agree with you. I do *sometimes* convert my comments into Answers (sometimes, *prompted* by comments such as yours! :), but not always. Also note that I very often provide some kind of comment / "answer" when *closevoting* - and obviously I'm even less likely to change my mind in *that* situation. *Finally*, note that if other users here upvote one of your "nags", that would usually encourage me to pay it more attention! :)

Comment: That's OK!  I was asking in the full expectation that you might say yes or no.  Cheers!

Comment: The sporting use of this term is definitely in the dictionary. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/round